# Each affine transformation $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, wose derivative doesn't have eigenvalue 1, has a fixed point

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Please help me prove, that each affine transformation $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, whose derivative (the linear transformation connected with this affine transformation) doesn't have eigenvalue 1, has a fixed point.

Comment: Are you sure you mean plain $\Bbb R$, not $\Bbb R^n$? Eigenvalue problems are usually posed in dimensions higher than$~1$.

Comment: Should be $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Then you should edit that into your question. Also, by "constant point", do you mean a fixed point? If so, please also amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start by proving that every affine transformation $\mathbb{R \to R}$ is of the form $x \mapsto ax + b$ where $x \mapsto ax$ is the "derivative" that you speak of.  The eigenvalue of this derivative is exactly $a$, so then you show that the assumption $a \neq 1$ allows you to solve the equation $x = ax + b$.

**Edit:** For the $\mathbb R^n$ case the solution is pretty much the same, only $a$ and $b$ will be matrices.  The equation you have to solve is $(I-a)x = b$.  You show that it can be solved by showing that the matrix $I-a$ is invertible.  Do this by showing that it's determinant $|I - a|$ is non-zero (note that $|I - a|$ is exactly the value you get when plugging a $1$ into the characteristic polynomial $\chi_a(t) = |tI - a|$ of $a$).